# undefined is not a function (near '...state.map...')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

When I load todos from storage, I get this error. When I replace the `loadDate()` function with `[]` this error is not present, but then I cannot get the saved todos from the phone storage. Help me please.The problem may be related to the wrong procedure. I had this before I used `useReduce()`

```
const saveData = async () => {
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state))
}
const loadData = async () => {
    try {
        const load = JSON.parse(await SecureStore.getItemAsync(STORAGE_KEY) || JSON.stringify([]))
        if (load != null) {
            return load
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert (e)
    } 
}

const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, loadData())

useEffect(() => {
    saveData()
}, [state])
```

Comment: Your state does not contain an array at the time you are using `map` on it - it contains a promise. That is why you are getting that error. You should populate that state in an useEffect instead. If you are going to use `map` to iterate over it, make sure you set the state to be an array.

Comment: Can you tell me what I should write so that I can solve the problem?

Comment: @Shandy Dispatch an action that sets the data in an effect and set default state to an empty array. The effect can dispatch when`SecureStore.getItemAsync` is **resolved**.